# How to set iOS orientations in cordova config.xml for universal app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a universal app and want only portrait orientation for iPhone and landscape for iPad. I don't believe I can just do,

`<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />`

because I can't see how it would differentiate between phone and tablet. Currently I've got this in the root:

```
...
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="foo-Info.plist" platform="ios" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations">
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        </array>
    </config-file>

    <config-file target="foo-Info.plist" platform="ios" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad">
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
    </config-file>
...
</platform>
...
```

1. Why doesn't this update my app's foo-Info.plist? I have tried `cordova build ios` and I have tried `cordova prepare` commands, neither update the plist file.
2. When should these changes take effect? When I add the ios platform? when I do `cordova build ios`?
3. I also need this to work for Android phone and tablets if you know how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i set deferent orientations for IPad and IPhone (Universal) app in cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497799/can-i-set-deferent-orientations-for-ipad-and-iphone-universal-app-in-cordova)

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to hardcode your app name here:

```
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations">
```

To get it working create `hooks/after_prepare/011_update_platform_config.js` file, take content from [here](https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic/blob/master/templates/hooks/after_prepare/update_platform_config.js).

Install some npms:

```
npm install lodash elementtree plist
```

`ionic run`, `ionic build` and `ionic prepare` commands should update your project files.

For more information check out [this topic](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/config-xml-preference-orientation-not-working-for-ios/6050/10)

P.S.: Your should have a strong reason to use upside-down orientation on an iPhone otherwise it's a pain for users (hello to iBooks).